# Sorting a text file based on substrings within a column in python

Tags: python

I have a set of text file data that is of the format:

```
19500101     9.2
19510101     100
19520101     28
19500102     33
19510102     34
19520102     102
```

I am trying to look at only those values in the first column where the final 4 characters are the substring '0101'.

I have used this Python for-loop and get these values, but I also get instances where '0101' is in other parts of string. For example: 20101231

```
for line in iter(f):
if line.split(None, 1)[0].find('0101') != -1:
    print(line)
```

How might I modify this loop to get my desired output?

Comment: [endswith](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith)

Answer (score 1):

Select the last four characters of the string using slice notation `[-4:]` and compare the result to your target value of `0101`

```
for line in iter(f):
    if line.split(None, 1)[0][-4:] == '0101':
        print(line)
```

For example:

```
>>> "19500101"[-4:]
'0101'
```

To guard against errors from blank lines:

```
target = '0101'
for line in iter(f):
    split_line = line.split(None, 1)  # Split line into two parts at first seperation.
    if split_line:
        if split_line[0][-len(target):] == target:  # or .endswith(target)
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `endswith` to check such matching based on the end of `string` to make it both more intuitive and more readable:

```
for line in iter(f):
    if line.split(None, 1)[0].endswith('0101'): //clear and intuitive
        print(line)
```

There are alternatives if you know exactly the char position too, just less intuitive:

```
for line in iter(f):
    if line.split(None, 1)[0][4:] == '0101': //start from index 4 from front till the end
        print(line)
```

Or

```
for line in iter(f):
    if line.split(None, 1)[0][-4:] == '0101': //start from index 4 from back till the end
        print(line)
```

All are valid though